Riemann integrability of the composition of an integrable multivariate function and a $C^1$ homeomorphism mapping

$f(\boldsymbol{x})$ is Riemann integrable on a volume-measurable bounded closed domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\boldsymbol{u}(\boldsymbol{x})$ is a $C^1$ homeomorphism mapping from a volume-measurable bounded closed domain $D\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ to the volume-measurable bounded closed domain $\boldsymbol{u}(D)\subset\Omega$. Prove that $f(\boldsymbol{u}(\boldsymbol{x}))$ is Riemann integrable on $D$.

The hint for this excercise is to consider uniform continuity of homeomorphism mappings.
The Riemann integrability of $f$ allows the existence of a division $\{\Delta D_k\}_{k=1}^K$ of $\boldsymbol{u}(D)$ so that $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^K\omega_kV(\Delta D_k)<\varepsilon$ ($\forall\varepsilon>0$). My attempt is to divide $D$ into $\{\boldsymbol{u}^{-1}(\Delta D_k)\}_{k=1}^K$. With this division, $\omega_k$ will maintain the same, and we also have $\displaystyle\sup_{1\leqslant k\leqslant K}V(\boldsymbol{u}^{-1}(\Delta D_k))\to0$ as $\displaystyle\sup_{1\leqslant k\leqslant K}V(\Delta D_k)\to0$. But how do these help us with $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^K\omega_kV(\boldsymbol{u}^{-1}(\Delta D_k))<\varepsilon$ ($\forall\varepsilon>0$)?
I am also curious about the necessity of $C^1$ here.
It should not be very difficult. Maybe I fail to notice something obvious.
